# Is it possible to hide specific Google maps controls

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API to display a map on a page. This all works correctly, but I'm attempting to edit the controls displayed on the map.

I've come across the `disableDefaultUI` option, which allow me to hide the entire UI, and the `mapTypeControlOptions` which appears to allow me to add my own controls. But ideally I'd like to be able to just hide the map/satellite option and the street view option (Leaving the zoom controls)

Is there a way to hide specific controls? Ideally I'd rather avoid rebuilding the existing zoom controls as that seem rather counter productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
var mapOptions = { 
    option1: value1,
    option2: value2,
};
```

For your specific purpose :

```
var mapOptions = {
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

You may find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls).
If you want to hide the *control* always put your *mapTypeId* after changing your *control* otherwise the option  will be displayed as disable.

Comment: Ah, perfect I needed the `zoomControl: true` thanks for the help!